# How do you make people drop extra items on death?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

As seen in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c_aTeVfDSpI#t=337), when a player is slain, they drop an Enchanting Table on top of their inventory.

How was this achieved and how can I build a system (using command blocks) that does that?

*Come to think of it, what happens to a player's location when he/she dies? Does it reset to the spawnpoint? Stay the same (where they died) until they respawn? Or becomes a null value until they respawn?*

Comment: They are definitely using a Bukkit-plugin. Looking around a bit, [Cookiemonster](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/cookiemonster/) seems like it can do the Trick, though it looks like overkill for that purpose. I found [this thread](https://forums.bukkit.org/threads/i-need-a-plugin-that-makes-players-drop-a-drop-upon-death.77957/) that has some code snippets that supposedly do the trick, but I wouldn't know how to proceed with them, as I've never done Bukkit-Plugins before. (Hence this is a comment, not an answer). In the case of that video, a custom plugin is not unlikely (-> Sethbling)

Comment: As far as respawning, it's UHC. Once you die, you're out of the game, so there's no respawning.

Comment: This should be possible, or something close to it with command blocks.  Although it would need to run on a relatively fast clock, it's not really ideal for multiplayer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## 1.13+ update

Since 1.13+, there are two methods to add or change a player's drops:

### Data pack: Loot tables

The new recommendation for changing what a player drops upon death is a loot table. Loot tables are JSON files that are part of data packs, used to dictate which items should drop in certain situations. To set a player loot table, you can create a a loot table at the file path `/data/minecraft/loot_tables/entities/player.json` with the following contents:

```
{
  "pools": [
    {
      "rolls": 1,
      "entries": [
        {
          "type": "minecraft:item",
          "name": "minecraft:enchanting_table"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

### Command blocks: Updated version of the commands in [Moddl](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/86828)'s [answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/188809/250180)

The commands in the other answer can be updated to work for Minecraft version 1.13+ like so:

```
scoreboard objectives add deaths deathCount
execute at @a[scores={deaths=1..}] run summon minecraft:item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:"minecraft:command_block"}}
scoreboard players set @a[scores={deaths=1..}] deaths 0
```

Comment: Oh, and make sure your JSON file is in `loot_tables/entities/player.json` in your behaviour pack.

Comment: @aytimothy The term “behaviour pack” is for Bedrock Edition. Did you mean data pack?

Comment: Same thing (in essence), different name; but yes. I use em' interchangeably nowadays since I work with both versions.

Comment: @aytimothy Great, just making sure you didn't mix them up permanently. Although we don't have a Q&A yet on data pack basic structure, maybe that'll have to come by later.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make a scoreboard objective of stat.deaths for example called `death` using `/scoreboard objectives add death stat.deaths deaths`.
2. Run a clock on a commandblock with the command `/excecute @a[score_death_min = 1] summon item ~ ~ ~ {Item:{id:minecraft:enchanting_table}}`
3. Run another commandblock after the previous one with `/scoreboard set @a[score_death_min = 1] death 0`

Comment: I get where you're going but, wouldn't the dead player continuously spawn a enchanting table every cycle of the clock, even after they respawn? (Which is at most about 10 times a second).

Comment: oh, i forgot about that. you'll just have to add a reset command that is ran after the first command.

Comment: something else, the fastest clock, the fill clock can run at 20 times a second - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SvTVjSLG9Rw.