# How do I cause a player to drop a special item when they die?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'd like for a player to drop a wither skull upon death, without the player being required to have it in their inventory before they die.

I have attempted using a scoreboard with the `deathCount` to track their death, with a `/execute` to detect a change in said score. When detected, a `/give` ran, giving the player a wither skull which they would immediately drop, under the grounds that they received the item before they respawned. The death count would then be reset to 0.

For some reason, the commands that I tried didn't quite work out.

**Edit:** Thanks for pointing me to [this other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/188752/250180). Unfortunately the answer there is outdated, so it doesn't help me. I'm on the latest version of MCJava, 1.18.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make people drop extra items on death?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/188752/how-do-you-make-people-drop-extra-items-on-death)

Comment: That answer in that post does not fill in the requirements for the specified version of Minecraft i am using

Comment: @bubbygameryt Thanks for editing and clarifying. First of all, please note that we're a site with high quality: I've edited your question to show you what a good-standing question looks like. Notice the use of `code font` to share commands and not **bold**. However, there are some things that are missing that only you, the post author, can provide. For example, if you could provide samples of the *exact and full* commands you tried (again using code font), it would allow us to get an answer more quickly.

Comment: @bubbygameryt I'd also like to commend you. Even after your question was closed (which can be discouraging), you did not give up, and you made an effort to improve it. For that, you've earned my upvote, and I've also answered the [other question](/q/188752/250180) with an up-to-date answer that is correct for all versions 1.13+. I'm voting to leave this question closed, but please don't see this as a problem. We like to collect similar answers all in one place, so this needs to remain a signpost to that other question. Thank you for trying your best, and welcome to Arqade!

Comment: \*upvotes new answer\* \*switches checkmark\* | Also more proof we need a "this answer is out-of-date" vote.

Comment: @aytimothy sounds like you could probably open a meta question on that, honestly.

Comment: @aytimothy The current recommendation for requesting up-to-date answers is with bounties, which I hate because only higher-up users can create them, not just anybody who finds out-of-date answers. If you do believe strongly in this, I'd highly recommend a meta discussion.